# Django forms not receiving input

Tags: html, django, forms, input, action

I'm using Django's forms.py method to build a form, but am not getting any data when trying to get the input by doing request.POST.get('value') on it. For every print statement that gave a response, I put a comment next to the command with whatever it returned in the terminal.

Additionally, I do not understand what the action = "address" is meant for in the form. Finally, the csrf verification was not working and kept returning CSRF verification failed so I disabled it, but if anyone knows how to get this working I would appreciate it.

forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Enter name:', max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def blank(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        get = request.POST.get
        print(f"get: {get}") # get: <bound method MultiValueDict.get of <QueryDict: {}>>

        print(f"your_name: {request.POST.get('your_name')}") # your_name: None


        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            your_name = form.cleaned_data["your_name"]
            print(f"your_name cleaned: {your_name}")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'blank.html', {'form': form})
```

blank.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ``action`` is empty. You should fill it in with the API.

Comment: @16350436, can you give an example of what I would need in there?

Comment: In ``blank.html`` ``action="{% url "blank" %}"``.
In ``urls.py`` ``path('blank', views.blank, name='blank'),``

Comment: @16350436, I'm still getting `get: <bound method MultiValueDict.get of <QueryDict: {}>>` and `your_name: None`

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this.. and must include csrf otherwise it will not consider post request..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Normally yes, but for whatever reason the author does have `@csrf_exempt` on their view.

Comment: @rob Thank you.. i didn't notice

Comment: @TariqAhmed, Hi thanks. I tried this but whenever I add the csrf_token I get the same "403: Forbidden CSRF token missing or incorrect" screen

Comment: ```{{ form.as_p }}``` Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes I added that